# vue3 unhandeled error when using vue-panzoom component

Tags: vuejs3, panzoom

I used the panzoom in an older vue2 project.

Now I tested the component in a simple vue3 setup and got "Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook at  at "

and "Cannot create panzoom for the current type of dom element"

where's the problem?

my package.json

{
"name": "image-zoom-test",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-panzoom": "^1.1.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"root": true,
"env": {
"node": true
},
"extends": [
"plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
"eslint:recommended"
],
"parserOptions": {
"parser": "babel-eslint"
},
"rules": {}
},
"browserslist": [
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"not dead"
]
}

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

// import vue-panzoom
import panZoom from 'vue-panzoom'

// install plugin
app.use(panZoom);

// createApp(App).mount('#app')
app.mount('#app')
```

and the vue file

```
<template>
  <!-- <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png"> -->
  <!-- <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/> -->

        <!-- apply to an image -->
        <panZoom>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
        </panZoom>

        <!-- apply to regular dom elements -->
        <panZoom>
            <p>You can zoom me</p>
        </panZoom>

        <!-- apply to svg -->
        <panZoom selector="#g1">
            <svg height="210" width="400">
                <g id="g1">
                    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </panZoom>

</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  background-color: red;
  position : fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I wonder if `vue-panzoom` doesn't support Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

`app` id is mounted in main.js using `app.mount('#app')`

But Div with id `app` is missing in the vue file.

Vue file will look like following

```html
<template>
  <!-- <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png"> -->
  <!-- <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/> -->

       <!--missing div! -->
       <div id="app">

        <!-- apply to an image -->
        <panZoom>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
        </panZoom>

        <!-- apply to regular dom elements -->
        <panZoom>
            <p>You can zoom me</p>
        </panZoom>

        <!-- apply to svg -->
        <panZoom selector="#g1">
            <svg height="210" width="400">
                <g id="g1">
                    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </panZoom>
       </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  background-color: red;
  position : fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}
</style>
```

You can refer to official documentation of [panzoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-panzoom) usage.